# How to disable the mongo .dbshell history file

Tags: mongodb, privacy

When I run the mongo client, it stores a history of commands in $HOME/.dbshell. I would prefer not to log any commands from Mongo.

How do I disable the behavior that writes to the .dbshell file? I don't want to write it to /tmp, I want to avoid having it write anywhere.

This page does not provide useful information [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, there is no explicit option to disable the `mongo` shell history feature.

A possible workaround is to make the history file read-only. The `mongo` shell will currently continue without error if the `.dbshell` file cannot be read or written.

For example, on a Unix-like system:

```
# Ensure an empty history file
echo "" > ~/.dbshell

# Remove rwx access to the history file
chmod 0 ~/.dbshell
```

I've raised a feature suggestion for this in the MongoDB issue tracker which you can watch, upvote, or comment on:  [SERVER-29103: Add option to disable writing shell history to .dbshell](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29103).

Answer (score 0):

You can control where this file will be created.

So 
take a look [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/9dfb28da2fbf9b1ba6b17ad873dde0db1863694f/src/mongo/shell/dbshell.cpp).

```
void shellHistoryInit() {
    stringstream ss;
    const char* h = shell_utils::getUserDir();
    if (h)
        ss << h << "/";
    ss << ".dbshell";
    historyFile = ss.str();

    linenoiseHistoryLoad(historyFile.c_str());
    linenoiseSetCompletionCallback(completionHook);
}
```

so if you return falsy value from this function the file should not be created:

```
const char* getUserDir() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    return getenv("USERPROFILE");//make sure this is empty
#else
    return getenv("HOME");
#endif
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I don't want to control where it will be created, I want to avoid it being created in the first place.

Comment: this is how they implement it internally in mongo source

Comment: @KevinBurke make the file `/dev/null`